# Are all apps localized to, say, Serbian by default?

Tags: internationalization, itunes

My app is in the App Store and I had pulled it up so I can share the link with someone. I looked at the languages and saw something really strange.

The app was listed as localized for several languages which I didn't use. I don't even know what half of those languages sound like.

**Is this a problem with iTunes, or is it more likely with my App submission?**

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Meh. My App is in Serbian.]

**Edit - iTunes Connect seems to read the same info from the binary:**

[image]

Comment: why single out Serbian ("Serbian Really?" (in bold orange font)) when Danish is just as odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your *-Info.plist file for suspicious lines. If nothing found, check your files for localization (in the File Inspector Pane).

Another possible reason would be the inclusion of a framework/resource (which is a bundle), that supports other languages. Check your built project for .lproj directories recursively with this command:

`find /AppDirectory.app/ -type d -iname *.lproj`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I realized that I was using Appirater, which includes several localizations. If you don't want your app to appear localized in those languages, remove the irrelevant localizations.

Answer (score 0):

Your submission, most likely. Check iTunesConnect and edit the details of your app, unchecking any languages you don't support.

Automatic localization occurs for default controls (e.g. an Edit nav bar button), but nothing else is automatic.

Comment: Ah, interesting, that's a change I hadn't noticed.